# Map from std::vector<unsigned> to Eigen::VectorXi

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a way to directly map a `std::vector<unsigned>` to an `Eigen::VectorXi` in the following fashion?

```
    std::vector<unsigned> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
    Eigen::VectorXi c = Eigen::VectorXi::Map(a.data(), a.size());
```

I'd like to skip the following step in between:

```
    std::vector<int> b(a.begin(),a.end());
```

Comment: The types don't match, so in this case you cannot map the data directly. If you want to put the `unsigned` data into a `VectorXi`, you'll have to convert it, in one way or another, to `int` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line

```
Eigen::VectorXi c = Eigen::VectorXi::Map(a.data(), a.size());
```

doesn't "directly map a `std::vector<unsigned>` to an `Eigen::VectorXi`," rather, it copies the data to a new `Eigen::VectorXi`. If you want to wrap the existing data array with Eigen functionality, you should use something like:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi> wrappedData(a.data(), a.size());
```

You can then use use `wrappedData` as you would any other `VectorXi` with the exception of resizing the underlying data (that's still owned by the `std::vector`). See the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) for more details.

If you're trying to avoid copying the data to a `std::vector<int>` then you can use a "custom" matrix type, i.e.

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<unsigned int, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> VectorXui;
Eigen::Map<VectorXui> wrappedData(a.data(), a.size());
```

Comment: I think that the main problem here are the incompatible types `unsigned` and `int` of the `std::vector` and `VectorXi`, respectively.

Comment: @RHertel I didn't understand OP that way, but I'll change my answer accordingly.