# Shared memory between std::vector and Eigen::VectorXd

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen, stdvector, eigen3

I am using Eigen for some linear algebra calculations and I am at a point where I need to interface this with another codebase, which is not aware of Eigen and is using `std::vector<double>` rather than an `Eigen::VectorXd` internally for storing elements in memory. The following (simplified) code is where the problems appear:

```cpp
void solve(std::vector<double> &vec) {
    Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::IncompleteLUT<double>> solver;
    Eigen::VectorXd rhs(vec.size());
    vec = solver.solve(rhs);
}
```

Here, I am passing in a `std::vector` as a reference and I want this variable (`vec`) to be updated as part of the solution process, (i.e. as part of the last instruction `vec = solver.solve(rhs);`). This, however, returns an Eigen vector so the above will not compile.

Two things to note: I am expecting the function `void solve()` to be called several thousand times per program execution and `vec` can hold several million elements. Thus, copying data is not an option.

The question then is how to map the data from Eigen to a `std::vector`. I feel that either using one of Eigen's internal functionality (Eigen::Map, Eigen::Ref?) may be of help here or to transform the `std::vector` into a shared pointer, though the solution I tried don't seem to work. I have also looked at using a `reinterpret_cast` on the raw data of both the `std::vector` and `Eigen::VectorXd` to no avail. I feel this should be possible but can't see how, at the moment.

This question is similar to the following posts:

- [Initialise Eigen::vector with std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036818/initialise-eigenvector-with-stdvector)
- [Map from std::vector<unsigned> to Eigen::VectorXi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843878/map-from-stdvectorunsigned-to-eigenvectorxi)
- [how to map a Eigen::Matrix to std::vector<Eigen::vector>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682743/how-to-map-a-eigenmatrix-to-stdvectoreigenvector)

In the above questions, however, performance overhead does not seem to be critical, i.e. here they only need to initialise the data structure, whereas I need to keep two separate `std::vector` and `Eigen::VectorXd` throughout the execution of my program.

Comment: Maybe you can take some inspiration from this upcoming C++23 feature (mdspan): [Multidimensional C++ - Bryce Adelstein Lelbach - CppNorth 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFCLmQEkPUw).

Comment: ```Eigen::Map``` does not copy any data and can directly reference the memory managed by an ```std::vector```. So the second answer you linked (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843878/map-from-stdvectorunsigned-to-eigenvectorxi) directly applies and solves your problem. So, which part of it is unclear?

Comment: you are right, I may have misread the first part of the answer (about copying), just checked, Eigen::Map does what I need, cheers!